# Using generics in Scala

Tags: scala

I wonder, what's the difference between these two:

```
class SomeClass(val a: Int)

//1
class Class1[T <: SomeClass] {
  def method1(param1: T) = ....
}

//2
class Class2 {
  def method1(param1: SomeClass) = ....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally? Say why some 3rd-party code has the possibility to load those classes will do the following:

```
class ThirdPatyClass(val a: Int) extends SomeClass(a) with ThirdPartyTrait
```

An instance of `Class1[ThirdPartyClass]` (and a reified corresponding `method1`) could be used where there would be a type bound of the form

```
[S <: ThirdPartyTrait]
```

whereas `Class2` couldn't.

And, of course, depending what you do within those methods, you could return an object of type `T` (or anything that uses `T` as a bound, e.g. `Class[_ <: T]`) in `Class1.method1`.

**In general, with `Class1` you're giving the compiler (and the developer) a possibility to preserve more information on the type of `param1`, in contrast with `Class2` where you can only preserve the compile-time information that `param1` is an instance of `SomeClass`.**

*EDIT:* to answer the question from the comment - yes, whether to select one approach or the other depends on what you need. If you require more flexibility and more static type information, go with the the generic type bounds. If not, I'd say you should follow [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) and not clutter your API.

Comment: so which approach is better or does it depend?

Answer (score 1):

`Class2` is both a class and a type, while `Class1` is only a class.  There can never be a value with type `Class1`, although there can be any number of parameterised types (`Class1[SomeClass]`, `Class1[SomeSubClass1]`, Class1[SomeClassType2] etc.), all of which have the same class and will, at run time, only be identifieable as `Class1[_]` due to type erasure.  This has some practical effects:

1. Type erasure complicates pattern matching.
2. Type erasure also makes various reflection techniques more difficult to implement for `Class1` than `Class2`.
3. Subclassing `Class1` requires more thought, as variance issues must be considered.

On the other hand, because `Class1` is parameterised, it is easy to mix in an arbitrary set of traits and know they all apply safely to the same type, without requiring any common inheritance or special equivalence methods.  The compiler will catch incompatible type operations.

```
trait Trait1[T]
  def method1: T  // Method happens to do something safely compatible with SomeClass
}

trait Trait2[T <: SomeClass]
  def method2: T
}

class NewClass[T <: SomeClass] extends Class1[T] with Trait1[T] with Trait2[T]
```